# Algorithm for constructing the corners of a regular, n-sided polygon

Tags: algorithm, geometry

I've googled this using a lot of keyword combinations, but to my great surprise I could not find an algorithm for constructing a regular, n-sided polygon into a given circle, i.e., finding the coordinates for the *n* corner points. All I could find were instructions how to do it by physical compass and straightedge, or interactive browser plug-ins without source.

So where could I find such an algorithm?

Comment: Let me restore your faith in the Google. ;-) Fourth hit for "algorithm regular polygon": http://www.gamedev.net/topic/463010-pseudo-code-algorithm-to-create-regular-polygon-with-x-number-of-sides/ "Then, using basic trigonometry, chose n points spaced equidistantly around the circumference of the circle (ie - if n is 3, chose 3 points on the circumference that are 120 degrees apart from one another)." Which is exactly what Kevin's code does.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To build the list of the vertices of a regular, n-sided polygon inscribed into a given circle, pointy on the right sided. Where (xOffset,yOffset) is the center of the circle.

With `i` going from `0 to n-1` inclusive:

```
pointX[i] = ( cos( i / n * 2 * PI ) * radius ) + xOffset;
pointY[i] = ( sin( i / n * 2 * PI ) * radius ) + yOffset;
```

Edit:
As Lars Viklund mentioned in the comments, this is only safe in languages like javascript in which integer division returns a floating point number rather than a integer. In other languages you should first cast `i` to a float.

Comment: Beware the trap of integral division in i/n in languages where dividing integers yields an integer.

Comment: Aah a very good point, I'll add that caveat in the answer.

Comment: This goes without saying, but you'll also want to guard against the case where `n * 2 * PI == 0` or you'll have one unhappy polygon :(.

Comment: Barring weird overflows the only n with `n * 2 * PI == 0` I can think of is 0, which as far as I know is undefined, same as i / 0. So no problem right? :)